# Maximum Consumers per JVM

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp

I'd like to know what's an acceptable value for the number of concurrent consumers of a given `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`. The default value is `1` (no concurrency), but I see that a vanilla `spring-boot-starter-web` project uses 200 threads for serving Tomcat requests. Should I use a similar value for the number of concurrent consumers assuming that the machine hosting the JVM is dedicated to this specific service?

Comment: In the old days each web server request required a thread for the duration of the request.  Hence to be responsive a lot of threads were pre created to ensure that a thread was ready at any time to service a request, so most of them were idle most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

200 as a default here seems exxessive.

You can use `concurrentConsumers` and `maxConcurrentConsumers` and the container will adjust on demand according to [a number of settings](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/amqp.html#listener-concurrency); full descriptions of the attributes [can be found here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/amqp.html#containerAttributes).

Comment: Thanks Gary. I had already read the docs, but as I'm a bit inexperient with Spring AMQP I was asking for an "empirical" limit... And in this case I'd prefer to use a "fixed" value. Is there a value you can throw?

Comment: There is no way to determine an "ideal" default for all scenarios; it depends on message rate/message size/listener processing time per message. If you expect 100 messages/second and it takes 10ms to process a message, you only need one consumer thread (maybe 2 for "safety"). If you expect a bursty rate (100/sec normally, but jumps to 1000/sec for brief periods) consider the max message rate and how long you can tolerate the recovery time to be.